# Configure ASP.NET Managed Handler to handle -all- requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I have a simple objective; I just want -every- single 404 error to redirect to a Single-Page Application for the SPA to handle routing.

This seems to work for routes that could possibly exist within the ASP.NET app (based on existing Controllers). However, if I navigate to a route that couldn't not possibly have been an ASP.NET route (which is happening, as some routes only exist client-side in the Vue app), it seems like IIS is immediately taking charge of the request and issuing this simple text/html response:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

The response is issued almost immediately from receipt of the request, which seems to indicate it is being immediately handled as a 404 by IIS before any .NET managed handlers touch it.

How do I stop IIS from doing this?

**Additional Info:**

ASP.NET Web.config error fallback is already in place:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/vue-fallback.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

This is an ASP.NET MVC Server; System.Web.Mvc v4.0.0.0.

IIS Version: IIS 8

ETA:

I ran the server locally (not sure why I didn't do this sooner), the exact error seems to be a failure in the StaticFile handler.

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

...

Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve my issue:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Vue-Fallback",
                "{*catchall}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "VueFallback" }
           );
```